# Troubleshooting Algorithm

Tags: javascript

Im working on an algorithm to return the provided string with the first letter of each word capitalized. While leaving the rest of the word in lower case. Looking for some insight to why this code isn't working. Thanks.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    let result = "";
    let words = str.split(" ");


    for(let i = 0; i <= words.length; i++){
    let word = words[i];

    for(let j = 0; j <= word.length; j++){

    if(j === 0){
    result += word[j].toUpperCase();

    } else{
      result += word[j].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
      return result += " "
  }

      return result.slice(0, result.length - 1)
  }
```

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: Tip: This is a lot easier to do with a regular expression and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a function that focuses on each word to do the operation. A simpler approach is to use the `split(" ").map(word => ...).join(" ")` pattern. There's really no reason to do a `for` loop and then fumble around with `let word = words[i]`. Remember: `forEach` exists.

Comment: Try not to say "doesn't work", instead explain *what happens* and if you get errors please include the *exact* error text in your question.

Comment: Ok I will remember these gems for next time, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are three errors in your program, that are stopping it from working:

1. You need to change `i <= words.length` to `i < words.length` (or `i <= words.length - 1`), since indexes start from `0` in javascript like most
   programming languages.
2. You need to change `j <= word.length` to `j < word.length`  (or `j <= word.length - 1`), same reason as above.
3. You need to not return prematurely, and need to change `return result += " "` to just `result += " "`.

- *Also although it does not stop your function from working you could simplify your return line by utilizing **[trimEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd)**.*

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    let result = "";
    let words = str.split(" ");

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let word = words[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (j === 0) {
                result += word[j].toUpperCase();
            } else {
                result += word[j].toLowerCase();
            }
        }
        result += " "
    }
    
    return result.trimEnd();
} 


console.log(titleCase("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the help!